# Laço de repetição em Java

Tags: java

Olá sou novo na linguagem Java, gostaria de saber como eu poderia implementar um laço de repetição toda vez que uma exceção do tipo InputMismatchException fosse captura, neste caso retornar para o inicio do programa para o usuário entrar com novos dados válidos.

Exemplo de um possível erro:

Enter account data

Number: "abcde"

unexpected error

Então neste caso gostaria que o programa voltasse ao o inicio para o usuário entrar com dados válidos.

Segue o código fonte:

```
public class Program {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);

    try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        System.out.println("Enter account data");
        System.out.print("Number: ");
        int number = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Holder: ");
        sc.nextLine();
        String holder = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Initial balance: ");
        double initialBalance = sc.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Withdraw limite: ");
        double withdrawLimite = sc.nextDouble();

        Account account = new Account(number, holder, initialBalance, withdrawLimite);

        System.out.println();

        System.out.print("Do you like to deposit a amount? (y/n) ");
        char r = sc.next().charAt(0);

        if (r == 'y') {
            System.out.print("Enter amount for deposit: ");
            double amountDeposit = sc.nextDouble();
            account.deposit(amountDeposit);
            System.out.print("New balance: $ " + String.format("%.2f", account.getBalance()));
            System.out.println();
        }

        System.out.println();

        System.out.print("Enter amount for withdraw: ");
        double amountWithdraw = sc.nextDouble();
        account.withdraw(amountWithdraw);
        System.out.println("New balance: $ " + String.format("%.2f", account.getBalance()));

        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Account Data:");
        System.out.println(account);
    }
    catch (WithdrawException e) {
        System.out.println("Withdraw error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("unexpected error");
    }
}
```

}

*O  programa tratasse de um exemplo simples de entrada de dados de uma suposta conta bancária (numero, nome usuário, saldo inicial, limite de saque), posteriormente é perguntado se o usuário gostaria de depositar uma quantia, e em seguida é feita a realização de um saque.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro: o uso de *try-with-resources* é interessante em muitos casos, por já fechar automaticamente os recursos. Mas no caso específico do `System.in`, não precisa fechá-lo (leia mais sobre isso [aqui](/a/380458/112052) e [aqui](/a/380696/112052)).

---

Sobre o problema de repetir/voltar ao início, a princípio bastaria fazer algo como:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
while (true) {
    try {
        // ler os dados

        break; // se chegou aqui é porque não deu erro, então interrompe o *loop*
    } catch(InputMismatchException e) {
        // erro
        sc.nextLine();
    }
}
```

Ou seja, se der algum erro, cai no `catch` e o `while` continua executando. Somente se chegar no final do bloco `try`, depois que tudo já foi lido, aí o *loop* é interrompido.

Mas essa não é uma abordagem muito inteligente. Imagine que você já leu quase todos os dados, e só no último dá erro. Nesse caso, ele vai voltar para o início e o usuário vai ter que digitar tudo de novo (inclusive os primeiros dados que estavam corretos).

Em vez disso, não seria melhor que ele digitasse novamente só o dado que deu erro?

---

Sendo assim, eu criaria métodos separados para ler números inteiros e `double`. Algo assim:

```
static int lerInt(Scanner sc, String mensagem) {
    while (true) {
        System.out.print(mensagem);
        try {
            return Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Não foi digitado um número inteiro válido, tente novamente");
        }
    }
}

static double lerDouble(Scanner sc, String mensagem) {
    while (true) {
        System.out.print(mensagem);
        try {
            return Double.parseDouble(sc.nextLine());
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Não foi digitado um número válido, tente novamente");
        }
    }
}
```

Repare que em vez de usar `nextInt` e `nextDouble`, eu uso `nextLine` para ler tudo que foi digitado (até que o usuário dê <kbd>ENTER</kbd>) e tento converter para número (com isso elimino a necessidade de ficar chamando `nextLine` logo depois, como você fez em alguns pontos do código). Enquanto a informação digitada não for um número, é pedido que digite novamente.

Assim, você só pede para o usuário digitar de novo o dado que deu erro, não precisando repetir os demais. Então o código de leitura nem precisaria mais capturar o `InputMismatchException`:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter account data");
int number = lerInt(sc, "Number: ");
System.out.print("Holder: ");
String holder = sc.nextLine();
System.out.print("Initial balance: ");
double initialBalance = lerDouble(sc, "Initial balance: ");
double withdrawLimite = lerDouble(sc, "Withdraw limit:");

Account account = new Account(number, holder, initialBalance, withdrawLimite);

System.out.println();
System.out.print("Do you like to deposit a amount? (y/n) ");
if ("y".equals(sc.nextLine())) {
    double amountDeposit = lerDouble(sc, "Enter amount for deposit:");
    account.deposit(amountDeposit);
    System.out.printf("New balance: $ %.2f\n", account.getBalance());
}

System.out.println();

double amountWithdraw = lerDouble(sc, "Enter amount for withdraw: ");
account.withdraw(amountWithdraw);
System.out.printf("New balance: $ %.2f\n\n", account.getBalance());

System.out.println("Account Data:\n" + account);
```

Claro, se quiser ainda pode capturar o `WithdrawException`.